# Consulta DIV y botones bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, div

Les pido ayuda porfa.
Tengo un DIV con 3 botones y el último debe desplegar una lista, pero la lista aparece al principio de la página y no bajo el botón...
Este es el código:

```
<div class="contenedor_botones">
     <div class="row col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12  container">
        <button type="Button" style="margin-left:25px; margin-top:13px;" class="b1 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#t1,#t2,#t3,#f1,#f2,#fil1,#fil2">DESAGREGAR CIFRAS</button>
                <button type="Button" style="margin-left:25px; margin-top:13px;" class="b2 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3" id="ocultar">OCULTAR / MOSTRAR  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> </button>
                  <div class="btn-group">
                    <button type="Button" style="margin-left:25px; margin-top:13px;" class="b3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3" data-toggle="dropdown" >DESCARGAR</button>
                           <ul style="margin-left:25px;width:300px;" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                  <li><a href="#">Informe 1</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="#">Informe 2</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="#">Informe 3</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="#">Informe 4</a></li>
                           </ul>
 
                  </div> 
     </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido. Cual version de bootstrap esta utilizando?

Comment: lo que usted quiere hacer es que al seleccionar el button con la clase **b3** esta le muestre las 3 opciones que ha colocado en su <ul>?

Comment: Hola, v3.4.1 Gracias

Comment: Efectivamente. Al presionar el b3 se despligue el menù, pero debajo el mismo boton... actualmente se despliega en otro lugar de la pàgina.

Answer (score 0):

Esto resuelve tu problema que "se desplieguen las opciones debajo del button". Solo tendrias que revisar el style de tus botones porque añadiendo los nuevos div, cambiaron sus estilos.

```
  <div class="contenedor_botones">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 ">
        <div class=" col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
          <button type="Button" style="margin-left:25px; margin-top:13px;" class="b1 " data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#t1,#t2,#t3,#f1,#f2,#fil1,#fil2">DESAGREGAR CIFRAS</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3"> 
          <button type="Button" style="margin-left:25px; margin-top:13px;" class="b2 " id="ocultar">OCULTAR / MOSTRAR  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> </button>

        </div>
        <div class="dropdown col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
            <button type="Button" style="margin-left:25px; margin-top:13px;" class="b3 " data-toggle="dropdown" >DESCARGAR</button>
              <ul style="margin-left:25px;width:300px;" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Informe 1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Informe 2</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Informe 3</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Informe 4</a></li>
              </ul>
        </div> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Lilibeth, funcionò perfecto. Debo modificar el estilo, pero nada mas.

Comment: Chevere, selecciona que tu pregunta se ha resuelto para cerrar tu pregunta exitosamente y valorarla. :)